# Homebrewed SocketImplFactory Causing Null Pointer

Tags: java, sockets

Exactly as the title describes, I've got a homebrewed SocketImplFactory that is causing my code to break on

```
(ServerSocket).close();
```

I'm at my wits end.  I'm now posting all the relevant files, as well as two runs.

First,  server2.java:

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.ServerSocket;

public class server2 {
  public static void main(String[] argv){

    if(argv.length!= 1){
      System.err.println("usage: server1 <hostport>");
      System.exit(1);
    }

    try{
      TCPStart.start();

      ServerSocket sock = new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(argv[0]));

      sock.close();
      /*Socket connSock = sock.accept();

      System.out.println("got socket "+connSock);

      Thread.sleep(1*1000);
      connSock.close();
      Thread.sleep(35*1000);            */
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      System.err.println("Caught exception "+e);
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Next TCPStart.java:

```
import java.net.*;


//---------------------------------------------------
//
// class TCPStart
//
// this is the hub of the entire socket implementation.
// all modules are initialized here.
//
//
// code that runs on TOP of this whole implementation will
// be put in this file, as separate threads.
//
// to start our implementation of TCP, type
//   java TCPStart <UDP port #>
//
//
//---------------------------------------------------
class TCPStart {

  public final static String PORTRESOURCE = "UDPPORT";
  public final static String LOSSRATERESOURCE = "LOSSRATE";

  static public void start() {

    // check command line args
    if (System.getProperty(PORTRESOURCE)==null) {
      System.err.println("Must set "+PORTRESOURCE+" for UDP port to use with "+
             "-D"+PORTRESOURCE+"=<num>");
      System.exit(1);
    }        


    // this number will initialize what port # you want your UDP
    // wrapper to run on.
    int portForUDP = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty(PORTRESOURCE));


    // initialize TCPWrapper's port number for UDP wrapping
    TCPWrapper.setUDPPortNumber( portForUDP );


    // initialize more TCPWrapper stuff here, if you want to test packet
    // dropping, or if you want to change the sending-rate limit


    // create an instance of the Demultiplexer
    Demultiplexer D = new Demultiplexer( portForUDP );

    // create an instance of OUR SocketImplFactory
    StudentSocketImplFactory myFactory = new StudentSocketImplFactory(D);


    // tell all Socket objects of this program to use OUR
    // implementation of SockImpl
    try {
      Socket.setSocketImplFactory( myFactory );
      ServerSocket.setSocketFactory( myFactory ); //This is the problem line.
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
      System.exit(1);
    }


    // start the demultiplexer
    D.start();

    if (System.getProperty(LOSSRATERESOURCE)!=null) {
      TCPWrapper.dropRandomPackets
    (System.currentTimeMillis(),
     Double.parseDouble(System.getProperty(LOSSRATERESOURCE)));
    }        


  }
}
```

And, Finally, StudentSockImplFactory.java

```
import java.net.*;

//---------------------------------------------------
//
// class StudentSocketImplFactory
//
// this object is what actually creates each INSTANCE of a
// SocketImpl object.  In TCPStart.main(), we call
//
//     Socket.setSocketImplFactory( new StudentSocketImplFactory(D) );
//
// (this is a static function)
// so, when we create a java Socket, it will make a call to
// createSocketImpl(), and the Socket will use OUR code!!!
//
//---------------------------------------------------
class StudentSocketImplFactory implements SocketImplFactory {

    // the Demultiplexer has to be known to every SocketImpl, so that it
    // can communicate with it
    private Demultiplexer D;


    public StudentSocketImplFactory(Demultiplexer D) {
        super();
        this.D = D;
    }

    // Socket object makes this call to get one instance of SocketImpl.
    // reminder: each socket will get a DIFFERENT instance of
    // SocketImpl. this is GOOD, so that we will have one TCPConnection
    // for each Socket!!
    public SocketImpl createSocketImpl() {
        return ( new StudentSocketImpl(D) );
    }
}
```

If I comment out the aforementioned trouble line, it all works well, until I try to actually accept connections.  A failed Run:

```
$ java -DUDPPORT=12345 server2 54321
java.lang.NullPointerException: null buffer || null address
```

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: Post the full stack trace.  Might shed some light.

Comment: You said "ServerSocket.setSocketFactory( myFactory ); //This is the problem line" and you said "my code break on (ServerSocket).close(); 
".  Which is it?

Comment: I can't get the full stack trace.  Spent an hour trying.  Also - the code actually breaks on (ServerSocket).close();, but if you comment out the aforementioned problem line, it prevents the NullPointer.

Comment: The only thing I can think of now is to run the code in the Eclipse debugger and see who is printing " null buffer || null address ".

Comment: (ServerSocket).close() isn't legal Java code. What is the actual line? And why are you using a custom SocketImplFactory at all? It's not necessary, there are other ways to skin the cat.

Comment: Chuck - That's a good idea.  I'll try to open this all in eclipse.

EJP - ...Really?  The line is when I call the close() method on an instance of ServerSocket, in server2.java  Specifically sock.close();.  Also, long story short, I'm implementing a TCP of my own for a class, and all the code posted so far is from the professor.  It's the framework into which I'm building my StudentSockImpl.  I was debugging his code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out my own answer, which probably won't make sense to many people, but I'm going to post it so that if Anyone else has a similar Problem, they'll be able to find this answer on the Google box:

Turns out,

```
(ServerSocket).close();
```

Calls

```
(SocketImpl).close();
```

Which I did not previously realize.  Since my factory was being reset to use a different SocketImpl (namely, the one I'm writing), when I tried to send a Fin Packet, it understandably didn't have anyone to send it to, so it gave a null address error.  Just goes to show, sometimes you have to sleep on a problem, and the answer will come in the morning.